# PDF.JS and QtWebEngineWidgets: adjust page and viewrect in pdf after loading

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, pdf.js, qwebengineview

I want to display a pdf with `PDF.js` and `PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets`. After loading the view should automatically focus on a given rectangle on a given page. The page and the rectangle can differ between each time the pdf is loaded.

I am able to jump to a specific page by adding the a function `jumpToView` to the `QWebEngineView` and accessing it manually by clicking on a button:

```
class MyWebWidgetPdf(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def jumpToView(self, pageNumber):
        js_script = """
                    function jumpToView() {
                      PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentPageNumber = %s;
                    }
                    jumpToView()
                    """ % (pageNumber)
        self.page().runJavaScript(js_script)
```

How can I extend the `jumpToView` function to also adjust the `viewrect`. The function should have the additional parameter `rect`, which contains the coordinates of the rect that should be focused on.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to the y-value of the rect, works with `scrollPageIntoView`. Depending on what kind of coordinates you have, you have to subtract from the total height of the page. The total function looks like this:

```
def jumpToView(self, page, rect):
    y = rect[1]
    js_script = """function jumpToView(desiredPage, y){

                        var page = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.getPageView(desiredPage);
                        var viewport = page.viewport;
                        var height = viewport.height;
                        var dest = [null, { name: 'XYZ' }, 0, 848-y];
                        PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.scrollPageIntoView({ 
                            pageNumber: desiredPage,
                            destArray: dest})

                    }
                        var desiredPage = %s;
                        var y = %s

                        jumpToView(desiredPage, numPages, y)""" % (page, y)

    self.page().runJavaScript(js_script)
```

However, I still have to run the function manually.